# Look through form and find empty fields

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form that when a button is clicked, I am trying to loop through checking for empty fields and then doing something i.e alert and then focus on the empty field.

I have this working but it seems to then disable the page totally?

Its goes to a AJAX call after the check so maybe I am missing something?

The HTML for the form is

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#check').on('click', function() {
    $(".form-control").each(function() {
      if (!$(this).val()) {
        var status_id = $(this).attr("id");
        var status = $(this).attr("data-name2");
        document.getElementById("status_id").focus();
        alert(status);
        return false;
      }
    });
  });

  // ... some unrelated code here
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Trading Name(s) * </div>
<input type="text" id="trading_name" data-name="trading_name" data-name2="Please enter your trading name" class="ad1 form-control" />

<div>Registered Company Name * </div>
<input type="text" id="company_name" data-name="company_name" data-name2="Please enter your company name" class="ad1 form-control" />

<button type="button" id="check" class="btn btn-check">CHECK</button>
```

Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions

Comment: "_alert and then focus on the empty field_" in a loop? Where do you think the focus will end up?

Comment: You are missing closing braces for your outer function (well, it could be the inner one). Is this a typo here or in your code?

Comment: I have formatted the code, so that you can see the missing bracket. Please verify whether that's the case in your code as well or just a copy-paste error.

Comment: Not missing them its because there is alot of other code after that but its not required here, its just whats executed after the check

Comment: @wayneuk2 I have added the missing brackets. Notice that if you click the "check" button you get an error.

Comment: yes looking at it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a minor error in the code. You are treating `status_id` as a string in the code:

```
document.getElementById("status_id").focus();
```

Whereas, looking at the code, it seems like you intend for it to be a local variable:

```
var status_id = $(this).attr("id");
```

So the fix should be to change the code to:

```
// status_id - the string, i.e. ID of the element in concern
document.getElementById(status_id).focus();
```

Or, in general, replace the entire line to something like `this.focus()` because `this` will refer to the element in concern.

Here's the modified snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#check').on('click', function() {
    $(".form-control").each(function() {
      if (!$(this).val()) {
        var status_id = $(this).attr("id");
        var status = $(this).attr("data-name2");
        document.getElementById(status_id).focus();
        // OR - this.focus();
        alert(status);
        return false;
      }
    });
  });

  // ... some unrelated code here
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Trading Name(s) * </div>
<input type="text" id="trading_name" data-name="trading_name" data-name2="Please enter your trading name" class="ad1 form-control" />

<div>Registered Company Name * </div>
<input type="text" id="company_name" data-name="company_name" data-name2="Please enter your company name" class="ad1 form-control" />

<button type="button" id="check" class="btn btn-check">CHECK</button>
```

---

Update:

[To show tooltips on error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51980462/look-through-form-and-find-empty-fields/51980659?noredirect=1#comment90911802_51980659), you would need to initialize the tooltips `$(this).tooltip()` and then open then `$(this).tooltip('open')`. Similarly if you need to hide them on blur or any other event, you can call `$(this).tooltip('close')`.

Here's an example:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // Set the title using data-name2
  $(".form-control").each(function() {
    var tooltipText = $(this).data("name2");
    $(this).attr("title", tooltipText);
  });

  $('#check').on('click', function() {
    $(".form-control").each(function() {
      if (!$(this).val()) {
        var status_id = $(this).attr("id");
        var status = $(this).attr("data-name2");
        document.getElementById(status_id).focus();
        // OR - this.focus();
        // alert(status);

        $(this).tooltip();
        $(this).tooltip("open");
        
        return false;
      } else {
        $(this).tooltip();
        $(this).tooltip("close");
      }
    });
  });

  // ... some unrelated code here
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>


<div>Trading Name(s) * </div>
<input type="text" id="trading_name" data-name="trading_name" data-name2="Please enter your trading name" class="ad1 form-control" />

<div>Registered Company Name * </div>
<input type="text" id="company_name" data-name="company_name" data-name2="Please enter your company name" class="ad1 form-control" />

<button type="button" id="check" class="btn btn-check">CHECK</button>
```

Comment: Ha, it works on here, but when I put into the page it say 'SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input'

Comment: I have form form elements is that the issue?

Comment: No my fault, it seems to work, I will add the other part and let you know, cheers

Comment: OK, great its working good. I would like to add a tooltip when an empty field is found and again can do this when its not in this form but I keep getting error that cant call the tooltip like this???  $(this).tooltip("show"); and I use this before $('.form-control').tooltip({
    trigger: "manual"
});

Comment: @wayneuk2 I have added an example to show how tooltips might work. So you can modify the code to suit your needs.

Comment: lovely, thankyou, But again it works great here but when added to form it does nothing, not even an error!

Comment: Sorry my mistake again, works good but its always there on hover, this works but cannot get it to work in that form $('.form-control').tooltip({
    trigger: "manual"
});

$("#id_stock_btn").click(function(){
    $(".form-control").each(function(){
        if(!$(this).val())
        {
            $(this).tooltip("show");
            return false;
        }
    });
    
});

$(".form-control").click(function(e) {
    $(this).tooltip("hide");
});

Comment: @wayneuk2 You should probably post a new question with a [mcve] if you are still unable to solve the issue.